# Using import statements for packages and modules only, not for individual classes or functions

Tags: python, python-import, conventions

The [google python style guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/pyguide.html) mentions at 2.2 that `Use import statements for packages and modules only, not for individual classes or functions.`. 
Why is importing functions or classes bad practice? What errors could it lead to?

Comment: In Python, classes that are associated with each other are usually kept in a file together (a module). You do not typically have a 1:1 file-to-class ratio, like you might in other languages. I believe `Use import statements for packages and modules only, not for individual classes or functions.` is just telling you to structure your files in this way.

Comment: `from colorama import Style; from tkinter.ttk import Style` - both from built-in Python libraries. If you do both imports, one will be silently overwritten by other.

Comment: I think it is recommended to do this to avoid confusion (overlap) with the names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is typically relatively small set of modules available to import, but they contain hundreds of classes. Module names are usually unique, class names are much less likely to do so. Repeated imports of identically named class will silently overwrite them and cause bugs when trying to use them.

```
from colorama import Style
from tkinter.ttk import Style

print(type(Style())) # this will always be tkinter.ttk.Style now, colorama.Style is unaccessible
```

When you copy a snippet of the code if names include a module name it is much easier to identify which module various things come from.
Consider the following:

```
window = Tk()
label1 = Label(window, text="some text", style = "s.TLabel")
label1.grid()
window.mainloop()
```

Ok, we see `Tk()`, so Label is probably from this as well - let's do `from tkinter import *` and be done.

`TclError: unknown option "-style"`?

Yeah, it's because the code had `tkinter.ttk.Label` in mind, not `tkinter.Label`